# Divs overlapping instead of stacking on top

Tags: css, internet-explorer

I am trying to have multiple divs stack on top of each other. Based on the responses of previously asked similar questions, I used a main container with relative positioning and absolute positioning of divs within. I Even tried giving them z-indexes but the Divs are still overlapping.

Please find the html below; Response 2 fully overlaps Response 1 Div.

```css
body {
  background-color: #dbdbdb;
}

h1 {
  font-size: 20px;
  font-style: normal;
  color: #000000;
  margin-top: 0px;
}

h2 {
  font-size: 22px;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: normal;
  color: #000000;
  margin-top: 0px;
}

h3 {
  font-size: 12px;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: normal;
  color: #000000;
  margin-top: 0px;
}

p {
  font-size: 20px;
  font-style: normal;
  color: #000000;
}

p.dataTitle {
  font-size: 16px;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #000000;
}

.responsePanel {
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 1px;
  border-color: black;
}

.titleBar {
  background-color: #ffffff;
  border-width: 0px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0px;
  top: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
}

.titleText {
  position: relative;
  left: 35px;
  top: 0px;
}

.titleValue {
  position: absolute;
  left: 35px;
  top: 24px;
}

.titleDataSource {
  position: absolute;
  right: 128px;
  top: 34px;
}

.mugshotContainer {
  background-color: #ffffff;
  border-width: 0px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0px;
  top: 52px;
  width: 33%;
  height: 420px;
}

.locationData {
  position: relative;
  left: 5px;
  top: 0px;
}

.personNameContainer {
  background-color: #ffffff;
  border-width: 0px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0%;
  top: 52px;
  width: 100%;
}

.personName {
  position: relative;
  left: 5px;
  top: 0px;
}

.personDescriptionContainer {
  background-color: #ffffff;
  border-width: 0px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 66.60%;
  top: 52px;
  width: 33.3%;
  height: 420px;
}

.activityContainer {
  background-color: #ffffff;
  border-width: 0px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 66.60%;
  top: 52px;
  width: 33.3%;
  height: 420px;
}

.personDescriptionData {
  position: relative;
  left: 5px;
  top: 0px;
}

.personLocations {
  background-color: #ffffff;
  border-width: 0px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0px;
  top: 474px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 150px;
}

.personLocationsData {
  position: relative;
  left: 5px;
  top: 0px;
}

table#locationsTable {
  width: 99%;
}

table#locationsTable tr:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: #eee;
}

table#locationsTable tr:nth-child(odd) {
  background-color: #fff;
}

table#locationsTable th {
  color: white;
  background-color: black;
}

table#locationsTable td {
  text-align: center;
}

#response1 {
  position: relative;
  width: 95%;
}

#response2 {
  position: relative;
  width: 95%;
}

.outer {
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
  <div class="responsePanel" id="response1">
    <div class="titleBar">
      <div class="titleText">
        <h1>Game 1</h1>
      </div>
      <div class="titleValue">
        <h2>sas</h2>
      </div>
      <div class="titleDataSource">
        <h3>Data Source: </h3>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="personNameContainer">
      <!---->
      <p class="personName">xyz/p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="responsePanel" id="response2">
    <div class="titleBar">
      <div class="titleText">
        <h1>what</h1>
      </div>
      <div class="titleValue">
        <h2>xyz</h2>
      </div>
      <div class="titleDataSource">
        <h3>Data Source: </h3>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="personNameContainer">
      <!---->
      <p class="personName">blah blah</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

JS Fiddle

[https://jsfiddle.net/qe36n9hm/1/](http://jsfiddle.net/qe36n9hm/1/)

Comment: Could you please provide a fiddle so we can see what is going on?
It seems normal that your divs are overlapping since you give them absolute position.

Comment: Added a fiddle, actually changed the two divs positioning to relative but still having the same overlapping problem.

Comment: That's because you have absolute positioned elements inside your divs. An absolute positioned element is invisible for its parent so the height is null. You will have to change your code so everything is relative in order to get the result you want.

Comment: @marc, That worked, also one of the "top" property was throwing it off. thank you!!